# Why Moses broke the chain of command in the spies story?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

Previously, G-d appoints Aharon as Moses' vice. There are the 12 Nessiim, excelled in [probably] Torah and piety. Yitroh makes Moses elect multiple judges. In the previous Parasha G-d chooses the 70 elders not mentioning Yehoshua (not clear what his role was). In short, lots of high-rank decision makers.

In this Parasha (also Deut 1, 23) [undefined] people come to Moses and *offer* (not demand!) sending spies. G-d reacts somewhat unclear, but Moses does not consult anybody and sends the spies by himself.

The weirdest thing happens on their return. Customary, when the president sends a spy, there's a chain of reporting - the president, the commetee, the government, the Senate (I'm not familiar with the US gov. structure, feel free to edit). Considering the sensitivity of the [military] intelligence they gathered (acc. to Ramba"n it was all about military tactics).

However, when the spies return they talked straight to [Moses AND] the nation without going through the whole chain. I presume that talking to Moses or the 70 elders alone would change the results drastically, especially assuming that Moses already knew their attitudes.

What was Moses thinking: 1. not consulting the [significant] others before sending the spies out, and 2. allowing the spies to talk straight to the people without going through the formal chain and stopping the catastrophe altogether?